# ATA/ATAPI low level question

Tags: device, ide, host

I am trying to figure out what exactly is happening
on ATA/ATAPI bus right after power-on. From what
I understand - host shoud send RESET command, then
after some predetermined time send query to identify
devices on the bus. But in reality, it does not look
much like that. I have connected logic analyzer, and
from what I see there are flying some READ commands
before any WRITE (to send a command) happen. Why ?

Anyone know/understand what should be the actual
sequence of events ?

Report this post

Comment: http://hardware.forumsee.com/a/m/s/p12-29513-0565003--ata-atapi-question.html How many websites did you post this question to anyway? I myself for sure don't like to do work that someone else is doing already.

Comment: http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&p=1156075 and http://www.edaboard.com/thread315046.html

Answer (score 1):

Before any application layer commands are issues (e.g. IDENTIFY) there is a event sequence at the PHY layer which has to take place. So if you're looking at the bus with a logic analyzer you're probably seeing the PHY setup process take place. Assuming there's a drive present, the sequence is essentially:

```
            HOST                    DEVICE

STATE:      HR_RESET                DR_RESET
SIGNAL:                     ---> (COMRESET)
STATE:      HR_AwaitCOMINIT         DR_COMINIT
SIGNAL:           (COMINIT) <---
STATE:      HR_COMWAKE              DR_AwaitCOMWAKE
SIGNAL:                     ---> (COMWAKE)
STATE:      HR_AwaitCOMWAKE         DR_COMWAKE
SIGNAL:           (COMWAKE) <---
STATE:      HR_AwaitAlign           DR_SendALIGN
SIGNAL:             (ALIGN) <---
STATE:      HR_SendAlign            DR_SendALIGN
SIGNAL:                     ---> (ALIGN)
STATE:      HR_Ready                DR_Ready
```

(I skipped a bunch of optional, error, and transitory states). It's all part of the host/device negotiating the connection before any commands take place.

When you say "I see there are flying some READ commands", what do you mean by a 'READ command'?

Sources:

- [ATA dev wiki](https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Developer_Resources)
- [T13 ATAPI 7 (Volume 3 - Serial Transport Protocols and Physical
  Interconnect)](http://www.t13.org/Documents/UploadedDocuments/docs2007/D1532v3r4b-AT_Attachment_with_Packet_Interface_-_7_Volume_3.pdf)

Comment: First, let me thank you very much for very useful answer.
It is such incredible experience to have someone actually
_read_ your question and answer right to the point.

Comment: In the light of your answer my observation about "flying
READs" may not make much sense. What I have been referring 
to was about the momentary (10uS) state changes on DIOR to asserted, while /CS0=A /CS1=N DA0-3=0.


The reason for this whole excercise is that I am trying to find out how HOST figures out if it talks to ATA or to ATAPI DEVICE. I am probably missing something painfully obvious, because when HDD is connected it sends IDENTIFY DEVICE (ECh) command, but when ATAPI device is connected it sends IDENTIFY PACKET DEVICE (A1h). So, someway HOST knows beforehand what it talks to. How ?

Comment: A quck question. From reading recommended document I understand that sequence shown above is SAS/SATA specific. Is there any similar mechanism in IDE/PATA (which is the case here) ?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with IDE/PATA, but the physical layer is specified in [T13 ATAPI 7 (Volume 2 - Parallel Transport Protocols and Physical 
Interconnect)](http://www.t13.org/Documents/UploadedDocuments/docs2007/D1532v2r4b-AT_Attachment_with_Packet_Interface_-_7_Volume_2.pdf).

Comment: In regards to how the host knows if a device supports the packet interface, in [Volume 1 - Register Delivered Command Set, Logical Register Set](http://www.t13.org/Documents/UploadedDocuments/docs2007/D1532v1r4b-AT_Attachment_with_Packet_Interface_-_7_Volume_1.pdf), section 5.15 it describes how the device indicates to the host on reset if it supports the packet interface or not. Basically it sets the command block registers to a unique value.